# How can I import DATA variable from JS into a new VUE3 component, then print the data in html DOM? :)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, axios, google-sheets-api, vuejs3

**Reworked** the file again a lot of thanks to @Mythos, I have managed to get the data in JSON format but the data has no titles data names in the objects I want to iterate over it in the Vue3 file, but for some reason, I can't seem to export the data from the .js file into. Vue file, I am getting a weird error saying that the exported functions are not in the file...
'
**I am using Vue3.**
'

**File:** google-sheets-api.js

```
       //importing google api package
    //const {google} = require('googleapis'); 
//if i uncomment the code above it will freeze and not show page in vue
    const keys = {blah blah this works fine};
    
    //https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs
    //https://console.cloud.google.com
    //https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
    const getJWTClient = function () {
        return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
            const client = new google.auth.JWT(
                keys.client_email,
                null,
                keys.private_key,
                ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
            );
            // checking conection to api  we left tokens argument called but we are not using it
            client.authorize(function(err/*,tokens*/){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(client)
            });
        });
    };
    
    const gsrun = async function (cl){
        const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl });
    
        const opt = {
            spreadsheetId: 'blah blah blah', // this is the google sheets id inside the url of the google sheets
            range: 'Data!A1:L93' // this is the data range we are using from hola 1 file in google sheets we san swap to our own sheet tab name
        };
    
        let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
        console.log(data.data.values);
        return data.data.values;
    };
    
    export default {
        getJWTClient,
        gsrun,
    };
```

**File:** Funds.vue

```
   <template>
  <div id="sheetsapi">
  <h3>attempt to read data from data from gs sheets api</h3>
  <!-- here is here i want to print my data in i guess a Vue 3 let i in items loop  -->
  <div v-for="sheetData in sheetDatas" :key="sheetData">
    {{sheetData}}
  </div> <!--From your edit history, I'm assuming your data is in html format-->
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import '../store/google-sheets-api.js';
 import { getJWTClient, gsrun } from '../store/google-sheets-api.js';
 export default {
   name: 'Vue3exp',
   data: () =>{
       return {
           sheetDatas: {}, // the data variable is coming from ./google-sheets-api.js
       };
   },
   mounted() {
       getJWTClient().then((client) => {
           gsrun(client).then((data) => {
               this.sheetDatas = data;
           });
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
   },
 };
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It kind of looks like ` this.questions` has html data in it, not JSON.

Comment: You can't iterate over html data. If you're trying to display a google sheet page inside a different page then you need to embed it with like an iframe.

Comment: So you're getting an HTML-formatted string, and you want to render it in your HTML page?

Comment: yeah, i guess for front end project... but i really don't care how i get it, i just ant to print the data so i can build a cool ui.

Comment: Try this [Google Sheets to JSON](https://talentnett.com/how-to-convert-google-sheets-data-to-json-data-api/)

Comment: I guess you don't want to use `innerHTML`, but want to get the data as arrays or objects? Also, how are you currently getting the data? Have you thought of using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)?

Comment: yes, I just recently tried sheets API and I could get the data to node :D ...  but I am wondering now how to print in VUE for this one.. I am not sure what to do after I get the data call function in a js file, on this should I update my question? I will try to update this to my current resolution...

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the functions from your js file. Also you need to return your data object.

```
//importing google api package
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json')

//https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs
//https://console.cloud.google.com
//https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

const getJWTClient = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        const client = new google.auth.JWT(
            keys.client_email,
            null,
            keys.private_key,
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        );
        // checking conection to api  we left tokens argument called but we are not using it
        client.authorize(function(err/*,tokens*/){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(client)
        });
    });
};

const gsrun = async function (cl){
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl });

    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId: '10a44rqtdWcPQqYtBtne0ImmNOaqSuPsiM2YNiTdMiWo', // this is the google sheets id inside the url of the google sheets
        range: 'Data!A1:L93' // this is the data range we are using from hola 1 file in google sheets we san swap to our own sheet tab name
    };

    let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    console.log(data.data.values);
    return data;
};

export default {
    getJWTClient,
    gsrun,
};
```

And import them into your component file and call them there, so you can retrieve the data object.

```
<template>
  <div id="sheetsapi">
  <h3>attempt to read data from data from gs sheets api</h3>
  <!-- here is here i want to print my data in i guess a Vue 3 let i in items loop  -->
  <div v-html="sheetData"></div> <!--From your edit history, I'm assuming your data is in html format-->
  </div>

</template>

<script>
 import { getJWTClient, gsrun } from './google-sheets-api.js';
 export default {
   name: 'Vue3exp',
   data() {
       return {
           sheetData: {}, // the data variable is coming from ./google-sheets-api.js
       };
   },
   mounted() {
       getJWTClient().then((client) => {
           gsrun(client).then((data) => {
               this.sheetData = data;
           });
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
   },
 };
</script>
```

Comment: I manage to get the data in JSON, your answer seemed to get me far into getting the data exported to a vue3 file, but for some reason, it's saying me that the { getJWTClient, gsrun } was not found... which is pretty weird to me since you used export default..

Comment: vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:3264 TypeError: Expected `input` to be a `Function` or `Object`, got `undefined`
    at module.exports (index.js?364d:45)
    at eval (index.js?f447:22)
    at Object../node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js (Funds.js:6554)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (jwtclient.js?d465:26)
    at Object../node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js (Funds.js:1517)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (googleauth.js?0a40:37)

Comment: Its not about the functions. Could you try removing all the code from the js file, simply have a single line `const {google} = require('googleapis');`. And in your vue file just `import './google-sheets-api.js';`

Comment: Tell me if the error goes away? I'm thinking it is about your project setup.

Comment: I think my problem is that when I combine ES6 and Js the thing vue just doesn't handle it correctly combined.

Comment: Did you try removing everything like I said.

Comment: No, I didnt I was really tired that night the next morning I surrendered and tried another solution that was already built and it worked like charm. but i can re-try and if it works i will give you my reputation, I care more about solving issues than reputation :).

Comment: Would be cool if we could solve the problem together for anyone else arriving at this question. Check [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1620) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468809/what-is-causing-typeerror-expected-input-to-be-a-function-or-object-issue) out, sounds exactly similar to your error. I think its because of your client-side setup, so would be cool if you could test it so that we could see if its a problem with my code or not. I care about both, take care rest well :)

Comment: Did you ever succeed running that js file in browser environment before? Did you get the data? What was your setup when it succeeded?

Comment: Ok, got some answers, first of all the console was dropping an error of me having to update package json to : "type":"module", so i did, then it told me the const {google} = require('googleapis');
                 ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined...  i will go ahead and try what you recommended and let you know

Comment: discard the  "type":"module" because it gave me an ECMA script error, my bad, I did what you mention and I got this value on the vue page : [object Object]

along with this console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Proxy.mounted (Funds.vue?34bf:21)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6992)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:7001)

Comment: I tried the iteration on it like this : 
<template>
  <div id="sheetsapi">
  <h3>attempt to read data from data from gs sheets api</h3>
  <!-- here is here i want to print my data in i guess a Vue 3 let i in items loop  -->
  <div v-for="sheetData in sheetDatas" :key="sheetData">
    {{sheetData}}
  </div> <!--From your edit history, I'm assuming your data is in html format-->
  </div>

</template>

Comment: i added to the return o the async function : return data.data.values and the error went away but its telling me : Failed to compile.

./src/store/google-sheets-api.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/mnt/c/users/dell/apps/jeremy-davis/sheety/src/store/google-sheets-api.js
  21:28  error  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  39:19  error  'google' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings) I'll update my code question to current.

Comment: If you comment out the require statements, `google` will be undefined, of course. You should look up the error about `require is not defined`. I think the issue is you're trying to mix node.js server environment code with browser environment code. You'll need some special setup to make this work. Also, you haven't answered how you were able to get it to work earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237122/discussion-between-mythos-and-abraham).